# Error running update, MD5 hash not as expected

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

While installing update of our features and plugins I get error

> Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,my.plugin.name,1.0.1. MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 28831092d574f304a77cab2fef49e61b and found 9f70eaca4fbd4dfc2b85b05e0f73298d.

Jar signing happens during package phase of maven-jarsigner-plugin and this is done with Java 8. Also p2 build and update happens on local machine, so no network is involved. Any ideas on the cause of this error?

Comment: mixed versions on p2 directory?

Comment: Do you mean two versions of same bundle/feature? I don't see it in p2.

Comment: [MD5 is not recommended](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3159186/oracle-to-java-devs-stop-signing-jar-files-with-md5.html) for jar signing. OTOH, are you using the same jdk for signing and for eclipse?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz yes I do, and I wasn't aware about the change - thanks for the link.